# Найти максимальный элемент в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы

В чем ошибка?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
int m=5,n=5,i,j,max;
int a[5][5];
clrscr();
for(i=1;i<5;i++)
for(j=1;j<5;j++)
{
a[i][j]=random(100);
printf("\n%d ",a[i][j]);
}
a[1][1]=max;
for(i=1;i<5;i++)
for(j=1;j<5;j++)
if(a[i][j]>max){
max=a[i][j];
}
printf("max a[i][j]",max);
getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(a[i][j]>max){
  max=a[i][i];
}
```

Сравниваете `a[i][j]`, а присваиваете `a[i][i]`.

Comment: нет все равно не то

Comment: @parol - какую ошибку хоть выдает компилятор?

Comment: Только в строчке `a[1][1]=max;` подразумеваю полагалось `max = a[0][0]`

Comment: @parol что вот это вот:

     for(i=1;i<5;i++)

Вы работаете с последними четырьмя строками и столбцами (индекс 0 не трогаете)
Ну да ладно, пусть будет матрица 4x4. Пусть.

Но. В строке 

     a[1][1]=max;

Вы присваиваете a[1][1] значение неинициализированной переменной max (не надо бы так называть, ну да ладно). Если в max число достаточно большое, то оно там и останется

Comment: Вот еще 2 копейки: int n, m объявлены и инициализированы, но почему-то не используются. Интересно, что печатает printf("max a[i][j]",max); Грубая ошибка в индексах матрицы (впрочем уже отмеченная @parol).

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий код:

```
int i, j;
int a[5][5];
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        printf("\n%d ", a[i][j]);
    }

int max = a[0][0];
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    if(a[i][j] > max)
        max = a[i][j];

printf("\nMax = %d", max);
```

Comment: Про индексы с нуля (а не 1) тут уже в комментариях говорили.

А переменной `max` лучше присваивать в качестве значения не константу, а первый элемент массива.

Comment: @avp а где @derkode присваивает max константу?

Comment: Собственно, я тоже об этом думал. Может имелось ввиду не обнулять переменную max при создании и поэтому заменил int max = 0 на int max.

Comment: @alexlz, до "исправления" им ответа там было

   int max = 0; 

значительно лучше, нежели сейчас.

Comment: @derkode в добавление к словам @avp: какой результат Вы получите при `max = 0;`, если все элементы матрицы меньше нуля?

Comment: Конечно, в таком случае я получу в ответе 0, но rand() % 100, как я понял генерирует только положительные числа.